# Foreign Key Constraint syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm new to learning SQL syntax and came across this example in a book. I understand the need for foreign keys and using the constraint function in order to set the key to another table that is created (EMPLOYEE_TBL in this example).

My question is why it listed the line `CONSTRAINT EMP_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID)`. What exactly is the `EMP_ID_FK` portion? Since you just need to use the CONSTRAINT function to set a field on you child table to the parent table, couldn't you just write it as `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_TBL (EMP_ID));` instead?

Am I understanding this incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL
(EMP_ID    CHAR(9)    NOT NULL, 
DATE_HIRE   DATE   NULL,
DATE_LAST_RAISE   DATE   NULL,
CONSTRAINT EMP_ID_FK  FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_TBL (EMP_ID));
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Two different products, with some SQL differences.)

Comment: It's the name of the `CONSTRAINT` object.  You need to name it something.

Comment: @jarlh The example in this book uses MySQL.

Comment: @arooney88 "this book"? All the documentation is available online for both rdbms's. Your question is not unique.

Comment: @Siyual Ok. I had originally thought that was renaming the `EMP_ID` column in the child table, which didn't make sense to me.

Comment: You don't have to name constraints, but it's good programming practice doing it!

Comment: @IvanStarostin I meant "this book" as it's the book I'm literally looking at the has the example that I listed above. It's a generic example, but they didn't explain naming the CONSTRAINT object.

Comment: @arooney88 that is very sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clause `CONSTRAINT EMP_ID_FK` simply gives a name to the constraint. This becomes necessary later if you want to disable or drop the constraint. You are correct that the name (`EMP_ID_FK`) is optional; if you omit it you can also omit the `CONSTRAINT` keyword, as the clause `FOREIGN KEY` is enough to tell the interpreter what it is you want.

Naming your constraints is entirely optional but is considered good practice for documentary purposes and in case, as I said, you later need to do something with the constraint. If you omit the name, the database will automagically name the constraint for you, but good luck finding out what that name is.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Put it like this.

Table 1 has to have a reference to Table 2. Table 2 has a Primary Key ID that is a unique value, that means it can be accessed with this ID, as it is unique in all the rows of this table. Now table Table 1 needs to reference to that ID. You need to store that ID in Table 1 so you can reference to it and you know to which Table 2, Table 1 points. You use the naming convention Table2_ID_FK to know that that Field in Table 1 is a reference to the ID of table 2. The constraint is to set the actual relation between these tables.